# How to create a menu form with different buttons from a unity sprite without using NGUI

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I want to create a main menu in Unity3d for which I have taken a sprite as main menu window and many small sprites as buttons. I wish to write a script that I want to attach to my main menu and that will detect which button is clicked and what function to call. But I don't know how to do that. Can anybody help me?

Comment: You do realize the new UI system has been release in beta? If at all possible for you, have a look at the beta release and get yourself up to speed with that: http://unity3d.com/unity/beta/4.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the quickest option would be to display the sprites and add a "OnMouseDown()" script, you only need a collider on it.

More information: [OnMouseDown()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html)